# Nested views - how to access from the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my admin view I would like several sub directories for example:

```
admin/users/list.aspx
```

I also have:

```
admin/list.aspx
```

What is the correct code to access **admin/users/list.aspx** from the controller?

Or should the admin sub directories be at root level of View/ and then use routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to look at *haacked* post about [areas in asp.net mvc](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.
I Think I will use a more flat url structure until there is an "out of the box" solution then.